# ffmpeg error when using non root user

Tags: ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg and it works perfect if you are root or using sudo but it errors out when trying to use it as a non-root user.  I have performed the same install on a test VPS and it installs without issue so it appears to be isolated to this cPanel server.  I haven't been able to identify why.

**Non-Root:**

```
> ffmpeg -v debug -i 1.mov 1.avi ffmpeg version N-65949-g0ddb051
> Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers   built on Aug 28 2014
> 11:39:47 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis
> --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100   libavcodec     56.  0.101 / 56.  0.101   libavformat    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100   libavfilter     5.  0.103 /  5.  0.103   libswscale      3.  0.100 / 
> 3.  0.100   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100 Splitting the commandline. Reading option '-v' ... matched as option 'v' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
> Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '1.mov'.
> Reading option '1.avi' ... matched as output file. Finished splitting
> the commandline. Parsing a group of options: global . Applying option
> v (set logging level) with argument debug. Successfully parsed a group
> of options. Parsing a group of options: input file 1.mov. Successfully
> parsed a group of options. Opening an input file: 1.mov.
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x348fc20] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
> probed with size=2048 and score=100 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @
> 0x348fc20] ISO: File Type Major Brand: qt   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @
> 0x348fc20] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 698348 bytes
> read:39602 seeks:1 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x348fc20] All info
> found [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x348fc20] After
> avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 169190 bytes read:2333362 seeks:67
> frames:148 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mov':  
> Metadata:
>     major_brand     : qt  
>     minor_version   : 0
>     compatible_brands: qt  
>     creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
>     model           : iPhone 5
>     model-eng       : iPhone 5
>     encoder         : 7.1.1
>     encoder-eng     : 7.1.1
>     date            : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
>     date-eng        : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
>     make            : Apple
>     make-eng        : Apple   Duration: 00:00:07.15, start: 0.000023, bitrate: 781 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0(und), 41, 1/600: Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 480x360, 1/1200, 710 kb/s, 29.09
> fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
>     Metadata:
>       rotate          : 90
>       creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
>       handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
>       encoder         : H.264
>     Side data:
>       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
>     Stream #0:1(und), 107, 1/44100: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
>     Metadata:
>       creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
>       handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler Successfully opened the file. Parsing a group of options: output file 1.avi. Successfully
> parsed a group of options. Opening an output file: 1.avi. Successfully
> opened the file. detected 24 logical cores [graph 0 input from stream
> 0:0 @ 0x34aa3a0] Setting 'video_size' to value '480x360' [graph 0
> input from stream 0:0 @ 0x34aa3a0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
> [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x34aa3a0] Setting 'time_base' to
> value '1/600' [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x34aa3a0] Setting
> 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1' [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @
> 0x34aa3a0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2' [graph 0 input from
> stream 0:0 @ 0x34aa3a0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '320/11' [graph
> 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x34aa3a0] w:480 h:360 pixfmt:yuv420p
> tb:1/600 fr:320/11 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2 [format @ 0x3496b00]
> compat: called with args=[yuv420p] [format @ 0x3496b00] Setting
> 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p' [AVFilterGraph @ 0x348f320]
> query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x34bbe60] Error initializing threading.
> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x34bbe60] Error creating filter 'anull' Error
> opening filters! [AVIOContext @ 0x34967c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0
> writeouts [AVIOContext @ 0x348f1e0] Statistics: 2333362 bytes read, 67
> seeks
```

**[AVFilterGraph @ 0x34bbe60] Error initializing threading.

[AVFilterGraph @ 0x34bbe60] Error creating filter 'anull' Error

opening filters!**

**As ROOT:**

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -i 1.mov 1.avi
ffmpeg version N-65949-g0ddb051 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 28 2014 11:39:47 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  0.101 / 56.  0.101
  libavformat    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  0.103 /  5.  0.103
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
    model           : iPhone 5
    model-eng       : iPhone 5
    encoder         : 7.1.1
    encoder-eng     : 7.1.1
    date            : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
    date-eng        : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
    make            : Apple
    make-eng        : Apple
  Duration: 00:00:07.15, start: 0.000023, bitrate: 781 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 480x360, 710 kb/s, 29.09 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x27ed3a0] w:480 h:360 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/600 fr:320/11 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[graph 1 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x2800700] tb:1/44100 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:44100 chlayout:0x4
Output #0, avi, to '1.avi':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    make-eng        : Apple
    model           : iPhone 5
    model-eng       : iPhone 5
    make            : Apple
    ISFT            : Lavf56.3.100
    ICRD            : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
    date-eng        : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 480x360, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.09 fps, 29.09 tbn, 29.09 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 mpeg4
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
*** dropping frame 79 from stream 0 at ts 80
*** dropping frame 113 from stream 0 at ts 114
*** dropping frame 145 from stream 0 at ts 146
*** dropping frame 177 from stream 0 at ts 178
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=  204 fps=0.0 q=27.2 Lsize=     348kB time=00:00:07.15 bitrate= 398.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=4    
video:271kB audio:56kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 6.560985%
Input file #0 (1.mov):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 208 packets read (634624 bytes); 208 frames decoded; 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 308 packets read (56854 bytes); 308 frames decoded (315392 samples); 
  Total: 516 packets (691478 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (1.avi):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 204 frames encoded; 204 packets muxed (276993 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 274 frames encoded (315392 samples); 275 packets muxed (57469 bytes); 
  Total: 479 packets (334462 bytes) muxed
```

**strace and strace -e outputs:

strace non root:**

```
 579 clone(child_stack=0x7fd3bfd07ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fd3bfd089d0, tls=0x7fd3bfd08700, child_tidptr=0x7fd3bfd089d0) = 3        2637
    580 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fd3bed07000
    581 mprotect(0x7fd3bed07000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
    582 clone(child_stack=0x7fd3bf506ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fd3bf5079d0, tls=0x7fd3bf507700, child_tidptr=0x7fd3bf5079d0) = -        1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    583 futex(0x253b420, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
    584 futex(0x253b3f4, FUTEX_CMP_REQUEUE_PRIVATE, 1, 2147483647, 0x253b420, 4) = 2
    585 futex(0x253b420, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
    586 futex(0x7fd3c2d0e9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 32631, NULL) = 0
    587 munmap(0x7fd3bed07000, 8392704)         = 0
    588 munmap(0x7fd3c250e000, 8392704)         = 0
    589 munmap(0x7fd3c1d0d000, 8392704)         = 0
    590 munmap(0x7fd3c150c000, 8392704)         = 0
    591 write(2, "\33[1;32m[AVFilterGraph @ 0x253b0a"..., 39[AVFilterGraph @ 0x253b0a0] ) = 39
    592 write(2, "\33[1;31mError initializing thread"..., 41Error initializing threading.
    593 ) = 41
    594 write(2, "\33[1;32m[AVFilterGraph @ 0x253b0a"..., 39[AVFilterGraph @ 0x253b0a0] ) = 39
    595 write(2, "\33[1;31mError creating filter 'an"..., 41Error creating filter 'anull'
    596 ) = 41
    597 write(2, "\33[4;31mError opening filters!\n\33["..., 34Error opening filters!
    598 ) = 34
```

**strace -e non root:**

```
strace -e open ffmpeg -i 1.mov 5.avi
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib64/libasound.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib64/libSDL-1.2.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib64/libx264.so.142", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib64/libvpx.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libvorbis.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib64/libbz2.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libogg.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
ffmpeg version N-65949-g0ddb051 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 28 2014 11:39:47 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  0.101 / 56.  0.101
  libavformat    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  0.103 /  5.  0.103
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
open("1.mov", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)       = 3
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 4
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
    model           : iPhone 5
    model-eng       : iPhone 5
    encoder         : 7.1.1
    encoder-eng     : 7.1.1
    date            : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
    date-eng        : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
    make            : Apple
    make-eng        : Apple
  Duration: 00:00:07.15, start: 0.000023, bitrate: 781 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 480x360, 710 kb/s, 29.09 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
open("5.avi", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 4
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x26ff4a0] Error initializing threading.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x26ff4a0] Error creating filter 'anull'
Error opening filters!
```

**strace root:**

```
 579 clone(child_stack=0x7f4eb7c34ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4eb7c359d0, tls=0x7f4eb7c35700, child_tidptr=0x7f4eb7c359d0) = 3        383
    580 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f4eb6c34000
    581 mprotect(0x7f4eb6c34000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
    582 clone(child_stack=0x7f4eb7433ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4eb74349d0, tls=0x7f4eb7434700, child_tidptr=0x7f4eb74349d0) = 3        384
    583 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f4eb6433000
    584 mprotect(0x7f4eb6433000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
    585 clone(child_stack=0x7f4eb6c32ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4eb6c339d0, tls=0x7f4eb6c33700, child_tidptr=0x7f4eb6c339d0) = 3        385
    586 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f4eb5c32000
    587 mprotect(0x7f4eb5c32000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
    588 clone(child_stack=0x7f4eb6431ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4eb64329d0, tls=0x7f4eb6432700, child_tidptr=0x7f4eb64329d0) = 3        386
    589 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f4eb5431000
    590 mprotect(0x7f4eb5431000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
    591 clone(child_stack=0x7f4eb5c30ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4eb5c319d0, tls=0x7f4eb5c31700, child_tidptr=0x7f4eb5c319d0) = 3        387
    592 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f4eb4c30000
    593 mprotect(0x7f4eb4c30000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
    594 clone(child_stack=0x7f4eb542fff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4eb54309d0, tls=0x7f4eb5430700, child_tidptr=0x7f4eb54309d0) = 3        388
    595 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f4eb442f000
    596 mprotect(0x7f4eb442f000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
    597 clone(child_stack=0x7f4eb4c2eff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|        CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4eb4c2f9d0, tls=0x7f4eb4c2f700, child_tidptr=0x7f4eb4c2f9d0) = 3        389
    598 mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f4eb3c2e000
```

**strace -e root:**

```
    strace -e open ffmpeg -i 1.mov 5.avi
    open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
    open("/lib64/libasound.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/usr/lib64/libSDL-1.2.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/usr/lib64/libx264.so.142", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/usr/lib64/libvpx.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/usr/local/lib/libvorbis.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
    open("/lib64/libbz2.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
    open("/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
    open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
    open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
    open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
    open("/usr/local/lib/libogg.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
    ffmpeg version N-65957-gc6a3b00 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Aug 28 2014 13:37:32 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
      libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
      libavcodec     56.  0.101 / 56.  0.101
      libavformat    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
      libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
      libavfilter     5.  0.103 /  5.  0.103
      libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
      libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
      libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
    open("1.mov", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)       = 3
    open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 4
    open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
        model           : iPhone 5
        model-eng       : iPhone 5
        encoder         : 7.1.1
        encoder-eng     : 7.1.1
        date            : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
        date-eng        : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
        make            : Apple
        make-eng        : Apple
      Duration: 00:00:07.15, start: 0.000023, bitrate: 781 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 480x360, 710 kb/s, 29.09 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          rotate          : 90
          creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
          encoder         : H.264
        Side data:
          displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    File '5.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
    open("5.avi", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 4
    Output #0, avi, to '5.avi':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        make-eng        : Apple
        model           : iPhone 5
        model-eng       : iPhone 5
        make            : Apple
        ISFT            : Lavf56.3.100
        ICRD            : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
        date-eng        : 2014-06-04T21:40:27-0700
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 480x360, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.09 fps, 29.09 tbn, 29.09 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          rotate          : 90
          creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
          encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 mpeg4
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2014-06-05 04:40:27
          handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
          encoder         : Lavc56.0.101 libmp3lame
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=  204 fps=0.0 q=27.2 Lsize=     348kB time=00:00:07.15 bitrate= 398.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=4    
    video:271kB audio:56kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 6.560985%
```

Comment: Have you used `strace` to see if one of them is failing a system call that the other isn't?

Comment: No I hadn't.  I updated the original post with the outputs.  It imports the original file fine but errors out after that.  I am not very good at reading strace output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strace` output shows that the non-root run fails its second call to `clone` with `EAGAIN`. According to the manual pages [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) and [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), this means the system has reached a limit on the number of threads the user may create.

The likely culprit is the per-process resource limit. Run `ulimit -u` to see what the current process's limit is, then try raising it and trying again.

Comment: Fantastic! You were dead on.  It was the ulimit -u setting.  I raised it and it works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: An alternative would be to limit the threads used by ffmpeg with an option such as `-threads:1 4` I found that to work perfectly fine as well.

Comment: @mkern How did you increase the value of ulimit -u? Can you guide me? My operating system is Cloudlinux 7.9